# Programmatically Make a Wave using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I currently have http://jsfiddle.net/6GEfr/

This works but I want it to be like a wave. Rather than a 'v' shape, it should look like an actual wave. How do you gradually do this?

```
var height = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    $('#container').prepend('<div style="height:' + Math.abs(height++) + '%"></div>');
    height = (height == 100) ? -100 : height;
}, 10);
```

my css:

```
html, body, #outerContainer, #container {
    height:100%;
}
#outerContainer {
    display : table;
}
#container {
    display : table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#container > div {
    width:5px;
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: There are many different kinds of waves. The one you created is called a triangle-wave. Maybe you want to create a sine wave?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [`Math.sin()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) to model the wave.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TjaBz/)

```
var i = 5, height = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $('#container').prepend('<div style="height:' + height + '%"></div>');
    i += 0.05;
    height = 50 * Math.sin(i) + 50;
}, 10);
```

If you want to make the wave smoother, decrease the increment value and the width of the elements. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/asWW8/).