# Make divs that moves like a wave

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make every div moving like wave using CSS3 or JavaScript. I try a lot but can't do it. I want every img of this html will move like wave. In a word every img will move like a flag.

HTML:

```
<div id="stage" style="padding-left: 180px; height: 160px;">
    <div id="spinner" style="-webkit-transform-origin: 180px 0 0;">
        <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 160px;" src="image/1.jpg" width="200" height="160" alt="">
        <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-50deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 147px;" src="image/2.jpg" width="213" height="160" alt="">
        <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-144deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 120px;" src="image/3.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="">
        <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-216deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 147px;" src="image/9.jpg" width="213" height="160" alt="">
        <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-288deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 122px;" src="image/6.jpg" width="238" height="160" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    }
}       
#stage {
    margin: 1em auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
}
#spinner {
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#spinner:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
#spinner img {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in this recent question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417139/programmically-make-a-wave-using-javascript

Comment: it's unclear on the exact effect you want, could you depict/describe it **visually**?

Comment: I want every img will move like a flag @king king

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animating `div` in a wave form using CSS would be cumbersome, if you are open to an `svg` solution than...

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sQG5/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<svg class="wave" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" viewBox="-120 130 451 40" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" d="M331,160c-30,0-45-20-75-20s-46,20-76,20l0,0c-30,0-45-20-75-20 s-45,20-75,20s-45-20-75-20s-45,20-75,20" />
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.wave {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
.wave path {
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 990;
    }
}
@keyframes animate {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 990;
    }
}
```

Over here, we have first created a wave pattern using `svg` and later, we animate that using CSS3 animations, if you want the gaps between the waves, using lower `stroke-dasharray` will help you achieve that.

Tested on Firefox and Chrome

---

Also, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/M9Brh/light/) is a fiddle created by [@Loktar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322395/loktar) which uses JavaScript and CSS3 animations to create a wave.